# How to change the title via callback?

Tags: highcharts

I am building my stock chart and I want to dynamically change the title for the y-axis while scrolling to see the units of measure comparable to ticks. I can't do it synchronously because it has to be calculated from the yTicks array. Is there any callback formatter for such cases.
[image]

Tried via render and redraw event but all without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `scroll` event to `chart.scrollingContainer` and call `setTitle` method for y-axis. For example:

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  ...
});

Highcharts.addEvent(chart.scrollingContainer, 'scroll', function() {
  chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({
    text: 'New title ' + Math.random()
  });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/25h8bg7x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setTitle

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: It works thank you!

Answer (score -1):

many charting libraries provide the ability to use callback functions for formatting axis labels and titles dynamically. Since you mentioned a yTicks array, I'll assume you are using a library like D3.js or Chart.js?

Comment: I'm using highcharts